# gnome-mplayer to play on second screen with option xineramascreen

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, mplayer, xinerama

I am trying to make `gnome-mplayer` play a video in fullscreen on my second screen. I am using a Nvidia card with xineramascreen. Below is my ~/.mplayer/config file.

```
[default]
xineramascreen=1

[gnome-mplayer]
ao=alsa:device=hw=1.0
msglevel=all=5
alang=English,eng,en
slang=English,eng,en
xineramascreen=1
```

The options have no affect, it plays on my primary screen as usual.

Running `mplayer -xineramascreen 1` works perfectly, I just want `gnome-mplayer` to work since it's nicer to use with GUI and Nautilus integration etc.

Comment: Why are you using xinerama instead of twinview? I say that because I have your desired behaviour working here with twinview. As simple as dragging the window, going fullscreen and then future videos load up on that monitor.

Comment: I got confused, yes I am using twinview for my screen setup. Could please provide an answer how to automatically select what screen to play on, I'd be most delighted :)

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't remember last position.

Comment: Whoops. I'm using `gmplayer` from `mplayer-gui` not `gnome-mplayer`. Try that (if only to see if it works).

Comment: gmplayer remembered the position. Does gmplayer take normal mplayer options somehow? I honestly don't like gmplayer much, it always produces error messages, even when everything is working fine.

Comment: Try `smplayer`, also available from the repositories, which supersedes the abandoned GUI in mplayer-gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting gnome-mplayer, you can try exporting the display: `export DISPLAY=0.0; gnome-mplayer` (change 0.0 to the desired display).

Comment: What would display 2 be, 1.0?

Comment: If you have a nvidia card, `nvidia-settings` will give you the displays.